# using session variables inside javascript functions

Tags: php, javascript, session, variables

Could anyone please tell me how to use php session variables inside a JavaScript function? I have a php page with some option buttons and when the user clicks the submit button i want the value of the checked option button to be stored in a php session variable which i want to use on another page. which radio button has been selected is being checked through JavaScript. In the same function i want to store that value in a php session varaible.
Could anyone please tell me how this can be done?
If i use the session variable inside the javascript function it simply ignores it.

Comment: do you realize that PHP is server-side language while javascript is client-side?

Answer (score 2):

you could get the php session variable name in `javaScript` like this

```
   var varname = '<?php echo $_SESSION["variable_name"]; ?>';
```

Comment: i want to set the value of a session variable according to the value of the option button.this will not do the same.

Answer (score 0):

there is something called "Javascript Cookies", very handy for this kind of stuff came in good use when i had your problem.

here's the link: [Javascript Cookies](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

hope it helps you out!

Comment: Why use a cookie for something that can simply be put in a javascript variable in the page source by the server?  Cookies are for persisting things between browser pages within the same browser.  While one could stuff a session variable into a cookie, it seems like a poor use when you don't need to persist it or send from client to server on every page.

Comment: because a session is stored on the computer just like a cookie so i'm guessing that he might wants to use the value in another place too so with just 1 static value stuck on 1 page you wont for far now will you...

Comment: Can you offer any reason why a cookie is better than putting it in a JS variable as in nsjulliver's answer?

Comment: Cookies also get sent go the server on every request. It is better to avoid using cookies for this reason

Comment: a variable is only stored while you are on that page as soon as you leave its gone, when you use a session/cookie it is stored on the computer of the user for a long or short period of time and can be called upon any page on the website just as you would do with user details, you store the username on the computer as a session to then allow it to show on posts/profiles and what not, a cookie does the same except in this case it's made for javascript so for example if i fill out a form and store it in a javascript cooie i can stil call  it if i need that value on another page.

Comment: and with those cookies you don't have to cross your PHP with your JS, keeping it nice and clean

Comment: the value in that i want to retrieve in the session variable will be used in the next php page.can you please tell me what is the best method to pass variables between javascript and php?Can we make the two languages interact with each other?Is AJAX the only method?Please let me know at the earliest.Working on a deadline.

Comment: Ajax is not the only method.  Any kind of HTTP Request can send that data along, like POSTing a form or GETting a url with a querystring.